# How do I install the Java Access Bridge?

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-access-bridge

I tried installing Java Accesss Bridge for a few hours now. But with no success. The installer from ORACLE does not work (rolls back at the end without error message).

What do I need for an application that makes use of JAB. Do I really need some sort of installation or can I simply put some headers and libs together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after a week I discovered that Java Access Bridge 2.0.2 works just as an update of 2.0.1 and that JAB 2.0.1 and 2.0.2 just work with Java SE 6. Since Java SE 7 the Access Bridge is included in the standard JRE7. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Java Access Bridge is included with Java SE Runtime Environment (JRE) Release 7 Update 6 (7u6) and later. Java Access Bridge 2.0.3 is included with JRE 7u6. By default, **Java Access Bridge is not enabled.**

This link outlines how to Enable Java Access Bridge.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html